# Deflection Curve of Fixed-Fixed Beam Under Central Point Load

Tags: classical-mechanics, statistical-mechanics

I have been trying to find the deflection curve of a fixed-fixed (clamped-clamped) beam under a point force at the center...

but I could not find it.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let the beam be length $L$ and the point force at the center be $-F$.  The support forces at the ends of the beam will be $F/2$.  The equation for the forces along the beam is then

$p(x)=-2 F\ \delta (x-L/2)+\frac{F\ \delta (x-L)}{2}+\frac{F\ \delta (x)}{2}$

where $\delta$ is the Dirac Delta function.  The equation for the deflection curve $v(x)$ is then

$v^{(4)}(x)=\frac{p(x)}{E\ I}$

where $E$ is Young's modulus and $I$ is the area moment of inertia of the cross section of the beam.

Integrate the equation four times and solve the four integration constants with the conditions for a clamped-clamped beam:

$v(0)=v(L)=v'(0)=v'(L)=0$

and after some simplification you should get:

$v(x)=\frac{F \left((L-2 x)^3 \theta \left(x-\frac{L}{2}\right)+x^2 (4 x-3 L)\right)}{48
   \text{EI}}$

where $\theta$ is the HeavisideTheta or UnitStep function.
plug in some numbers to get a plot

[image]